# MailChimp and Stripe Integration for React

Tags: reactjs, forms, stripe-payments, mailchimp

I want to build a custom React form on my website, Where when someone pays a one-time charge using Stripe and if it is successful then they should be added to my MailChimp Email list. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be something you can do "[after the payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-fulfillment)" using the `payment_intent.succeeded` webhook.

You can either create a `customer` with that email address (recommended) or simply attach it to the Payment Intent as `metadata`. Then you'd [build a webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build) and set it up to receive these `payment_intent.succeeded` events. When you receive  events, you'd get the email address (either by retrieving the Customer or inspecting the `metadata`) and call MailChimp's API to [add a member to your list](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/add-member-to-list/):

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://${dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}/members?skip_merge_validation=<SOME_BOOLEAN_VALUE>' \
  --user "anystring:${apikey}"' \
  -d '{"email_address":"","email_type":"","status":"subscribed","merge_fields":{},"interests":{},"language":"","vip":false,"location":{"latitude":0,"longitude":0},"marketing_permissions":[],"ip_signup":"","timestamp_signup":"","ip_opt":"","timestamp_opt":"","tags":[]}'
```

or with the Node client:

```
const response = await client.lists.addListMember("list_id", {
    email_address: "joe@example.com",
    status: "pending",
  });
```